# Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a potentially basic problem for Eloquent.  I want to show only the name corresponding with Role of that user. I used the Eloquent Relationship ManytoMany. But I can't get that to work.

I tried point to the name using the `$users` parameter but this didn't work.

My project has three files such as **Role** model, **StudentController**, **find_username view**.

Thank you.

**Role Model**:

```
class Role extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id','role_name','role_level','role_note'];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'role_users', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }

}
```

My **StudentController**:

```
class StudentController extends Controller
{
    public function find_username()
    {
        $roles = Role::all();

        foreach($roles as $role)
        {
            echo $role->users . '<br>';
        }
        return view('find_username',['roles'=> $roles]);
    }
}
```

My **find_username view**:

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID Role</th>
                <th>Role name</th>
                <th>Role level</th>
                <th>Role note</th>
                <th>User name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($roles as $item)
                <tr>
                <td>{{$item['id']}}</td>
                <td>{{$item['role_name']}}</td>
                <td>{{$item['role_level']}}</td>
                <td>{{$item['role_note']}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->users}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: what is the use of the `foreach` in the controller? and what are you trying to get?

Comment: I don't see a property or key `name` being used anywhere in your code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you wanna query the `users` instead of the `roles`

Comment: If you print out `{{$item->users}}` you will see a json 'list' of all users who have that particular role. Also, **never** echo something out in a Controller. Except in a `dd()` for testing results. Send all data to the View.

Answer (score 0):

You have many roles.  Each of these roles have many users.  Your table will be fine as it is to show the name of the role, roll level, and role note, because these are on the looped `$item` variable individually.

The problem is that while the `$item` holds those singular fields, the `$item->users` is another *collection* of user objects. Which means you have added another dimension onto your table.  You might have 1 or 100 users to fit inside that `<tr>`.

To demonstrate, try this code, specifically adding in all the users names (adding the parameter to each user object in a new loop):

```
@foreach ($roles as $item)
   <tr>
    <td>{{$item['id']}}</td>
    <td>{{$item['role_name']}}</td>
    <td>{{$item['role_level']}}</td>
    <td>{{$item['role_note']}}</td>
    @foreach($item->users as $user)
       <td>
         {{$user->name}}
         {{$loop->last?"":" | "}}  //<-- just to separate names for this test
       </td>
    @endforeach
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

If you have your models and relations set up correctly, this will show you your users for each role.  However, as you can see, this may not be the best way to display this data.  You might have dozens of users per role.  You may wish to consider making a totally separate table for each role's users.  Maybe click on something for the role on this table and bring up a new list or table of those users who have the role.

HTH